# Max value of Anti-symmetric Relation

Tags: combinatorics, relations

Here is the question: Let A be a set with |A| = n and R be a relation on A that is anti-symmetric. What is the max value for |R|? How many antisymmetric relations can have this size?

So I'm not sure how to answer this. My first inclination is to just use the formula that tells you how to many antisymmetric relations there can be : $(2^n)(3^{n^2-n}/2)$. But then I figured that R can have more than just antisymmetric relations. My next thought was to count up equivalence relations and subtract the number of symmetric relations. I'm not sure if this will work, but this just seems more complicated than it should.

What should I be doing?

No clue on how to do the second part.

Note: Not homework. This is just me trying my hand at some practice problems for a test.

Edit: I'm saying the max value of |R| is .5(n^2 +n). I got this by adding n + (n^2-n)/2. I arrived at this by considering an upper triangular matrix. If this is correct, I'm still not sure how to the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bb}{\color{blue}{\bullet}}\newcommand{\br}{\color{brown}{\bullet}}\newcommand{\bu}{\bullet}$Look instead at where the formula for the number of antisymmetric relations on $A$ comes from. Here’s a diagram of $A\times A$ for a set $A$ of $9$ elements. A relation on $A$ is a subset of this diagram. If that relation is antisymmetric, can it include all of the brown dots? If it includes a blue dot, can it include the brown dot symmetrically opposite it on the other side of the brown diagonal or vice versa (like the orange/cyan pair)?

$$\begin{array}{c|cc}
&a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4&a_5&a_6&a_7&a_8&a_9\\ \hline
a_1&\br&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb\\
a_2&\bu&\br&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb&\color{orange}\bullet&\bb&\bb\\
a_3&\bu&\bu&\br&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb\\
a_4&\bu&\bu&\bu&\br&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb\\
a_5&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\br&\bb&\bb&\bb&\bb\\
a_6&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\br&\bb&\bb&\bb\\
a_7&\bu&\color{cyan}\bullet&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\br&\bb&\bb\\
a_8&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\br&\bb\\
a_9&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\bu&\br
\end{array}$$

**Added:** Every one of these largest antisymmetric relations on $A$ must include all of the diagonal pairs. It must include exactly one of each symmetric pair, like $\langle a_2,a_7\rangle$ and $\langle a_7,a_2\rangle$ in the diagram. In the comments you found that there are $\frac12n(n-1)$ symmetric pairs. From each of those pairs you make a $2$-way choice; how many ways are there to make $\frac12n(n-1)$ $2$-way choices?

Comment: this is horribly confusing. I'm more lost.

Comment: You answered a question with a question?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, I did: a question intended to point the OP in the right direction. You’ll find that this rather common.

Comment: @user9915: If the pair $\langle a_2,a_7\rangle$ is in some antisymmetric relation $R$, is it possible for $\langle a_7,a_2\rangle$ also to belong to $R$? If you prefer a more informal notation, if $a_2\,R\,a_7$, is it possible that $a_7\,R\,a_2$ as well?

Comment: no, it is not possible

Comment: @user9915: Right. In general each ordered pair above the diagonal — my blue dots — corresponds to an ordered pair below the diagonal (black dots) that is its reversal, and at most one of them can belong to an antisymmetric relation. You could keep all of the blue dots, for instance, but then you couldn’t have any of the brown dots. How many blue dots are there if we start with an $n\times n$ square (since $|A|=n$)?

Comment: (n^2 -n)/2 blue dots. and then we add n for the diagonal entries. This gives us the max value for |R|.

Comment: @user9915: Yes, that’s exactly right.

Comment: So how do you figure out how many antisymmetric relations can have this size?

Comment: @user9915: I added something for that; see if it’s enough for you to take the last step yourself.

Comment: almost. $2^{.5(n^2-n)}$ ways to choose the non-diagonal elements. But don't we need to add an $n$ somewhere to account for the diagonal elements?

Comment: @user9915: Yes, that power of $2$ is right. No, there’s no need to do anything about the diagonal elements: they all **have** to be present if the relation is to have the maximum possible size. There’s no choice there.

Comment: They do have to be present. That is why you have to add them.

Comment: @user9915: That is why you do **not** have to make any provision for them in the count. In this part of the problem you’re not counting ordered pairs in a relation; you’re counting relations.

Answer (score 0):

The first part of the problem is not asking how many possible antisymmetric relations there are, but how many pairs there can be in a *single* antisymmetric relation. (Remember, a relation is a set of pairs).

For example there cannot be $n^2$ pairs, because that would mean everything is related to everything else, and that is *not* an antisymmetric relation (unless $n\le 1$, which is kind of an uninteresting case). So there is some smaller upper bound for how large an antisymmetric relation can be.

Then it asks how many antisymmetric relations *of that particular size* there are. Do you know how to derive the formula you're using (which I think should be $2^n3^{(n^2-n)/2}$ rather than $2^n3^{n^2-n}/2$. It should be possible to adapt that derivation into a solution for the second part, once you have the answer to the first.

Comment: Do you have any help for the first part. Nor do I know the proof.

Comment: @user9915: Try to do some small cases by hand such as for $n=2$ or $n=3$, then. Look for patterns in what you do.